# Best way to deploy ASP.NET MVC 4 mobile app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mobile

If I create a ASP.NET MVC 4 mobile application, what are my options for deploying it to an iOS or Android device?

Comment: You still have to run those from a server and have the client (iOS or Andriod) hit them from a URL in the respective browsers.  Neither of those OS's will run a .NET project.

Comment: So I would need to use something like Phonegap?

Comment: PhoneGap only appears to use HTML, JS and CSS.  MVC is a server side compiled language that does not fall into those.  I am not saying there isn't something out there, but you are mixing apples and oranges in what you are trying to accomplish :/

Comment: ASP.NET MVC 4 has mobile support.  I would be using Kendo UI Mobile or Jquery mobile along with it.  Then I would like to contact the existing code libraries as I currently do with my web applications.  I just don't know how this would be deployed to a device.

Comment: has mobile support for viewing through a mobile browser, not deploying through an app store.

Comment: So for users to connect to this application, they would go the same process as for connecting to any web application.  Is it possible to create an icon outside the browser that behaves like a native app even though it's just opens a browser.

Comment: They can install a shortcut on their home screen.  I have no idea if you can do that from your website or not (I am leaning toward no)

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea how well this works, but you could look into something like http://xamarin.com/.  It uses C# (most likely not the MVC framework however). There are most likely others, but at least you know something exists out there that may help in what you are looking for.